# Error with inserting datetime in database

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Currently I'm trying to insert a datetime value into the datebase. But the error:

> "Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '/'."

keeps showing up.

This is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = SqlConn.openSqlConnection();
conn.Open();
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("makeRit", conn);
comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
checkRitNr();
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nr",ritnr);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", ritValue[0]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Beginstand", ritValue[1]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eindstand", ritValue[2]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Van", ritValue[3]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naar", ritValue[4]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bezoekadres", ritValue[5]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Geredenroute", ritValue[6]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Karakterrit", ritValue[7]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Toelichting", ritValue[8]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kilometerszakelijk", ritValue[9]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kilometersprive", ritValue[10]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Today); 
added = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

And this is the stored procedure:

```
@username varchar(50),
@Nr int,
@Datum varchar(50),
@Beginstand varchar(50),
@Eindstand varchar(50),
@Van varchar(50),
@Naar varchar(50),
@Bezoekadres varchar(50),
@Geredenroute varchar(50),
@karakterrit varchar(50),
@Toelichting varchar(50),
@kilometerszakelijk varchar(50),
@kilometersprive varchar(50),
@date datetime
as
begin
Exec ('insert into'+@username+'ritteninformatie'+'values('+@Nr+','+@Datum+','+@Beginstand+','+@Eindstand+','+@Van+','+@Naar+','+@Bezoekadres+','+@Geredenroute+','+@Karakterrit+','+@Toelichting+','+@Kilometerszakelijk+','+@Kilometersprive+','+@date)
end
```

I'm trying to insert the date of today, in "date" that has "datetime" value. I've to insert it as datetime and not as a string.

Comment: Did you debug your code and see your values? What is your insert query looks like after you add your parameters?

Comment: The variable date is "06/05/2015 12:00:00 AM}.

Comment: Do you get any error when using `sp_executesql` with this date?

Comment: Nope your code works great. But I just wanted to give the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sp_executeSQL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188001.aspx) instead of `EXEC` directly and pass your variables as parameters to `sp_executeSQL` like this.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'insert into '+@username+'ritteninformatie'+' values(
@Nr,@Datum,@Beginstand,@Eindstand,@Van,@Naar,@Bezoekadres,@Geredenroute,@Karakterrit,@Toelichting,@Kilometerszakelijk,@Kilometersprive,@date)'


EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql,N'@Nr int,
@Datum varchar(50),
@Beginstand varchar(50),
@Eindstand varchar(50),
@Van varchar(50),
@Naar varchar(50),
@Bezoekadres varchar(50),
@Geredenroute varchar(50),
@karakterrit varchar(50),
@Toelichting varchar(50),
@kilometerszakelijk varchar(50),
@kilometersprive varchar(50),
@date datetime',@Nr,@Datum,@Beginstand,@Eindstand,@Van,@Naar,@Bezoekadres,@Geredenroute,@Karakterrit,@Toelichting,@Kilometerszakelijk,@Kilometersprive,@date
```

Comment: you are welcome. for more info on `sp_executesql` check [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188001.aspx)